# Overriding CSS styles for a particular DIV?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to override the default font styling for a specific section of my site, but can't get it to work. The default paragraph settings override the DIV stylings.

I have my default paragraph font set as follows:

```
p {
color: #000000;
font: 15px/24px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

I'm trying to get my footer font smaller by styling the DIV like so:

```
#footer-disclaimers-freedvd {
color: #656565;
font: 12px/18px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="footer-disclaimers-freedvd">
<p>some text....</p>
</div>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You just have to add the paragraph to your selector

```
#footer-disclaimers-freedvd p {
color: #656565;
font: 12px/18px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector needs to be more specific

```
#footer-disclaimers-freedvd p { insert styles }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the `<p>` element like so:

```
#footer-disclaimers-freedvd p{
    color: #656565;
    font: 12px/18px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if your sure that your targeting your element and it still doesn't work try adding '!important'. For example div.class{margin-left:10px !important;}